# Exeunt, fighting

Tags: phraseology

Blocking's a female dog.

Blocking is what the playwright writes when they're not writing dialogue. Blocking tells the actors what to do with their limbs and where to position themselves on the stage when they're not talking. Blocking should be brief and to the point. Blocking should explain to the director, stage manager, stage hands, and the lighting staff in as few words as possible what to tell the actors. No one ever reads blocking until it's too late.

Now. It's the middle of Act 2. The stage is empty. Suddenly we (the audience) hear the patter of feet. Someone's rushing in! The lead woman! She's upset. No! She's infuriated. She's running down the steps and is about to enter, stage-right. It's important that we hear the patter of feet before she enters. It's a plot device of some sort.

The author has to put that in the blocking, using as few words as possible.

They could just write (in Italics):

*Patter of feet off-stage!*

And leave it at that.

Or:

*Off-stage, patter of feet!*

It's been done. It looks tacky on the page.

Another trick is to involve an imaginary audience. Like this:

*We hear patter of feet off-stage.*

I don't like it.

You could write:

*Off-stage, patter of feet **resounds**.*

Sounds kind of silly. This is even sillier:

*The sound of the patter of feet comes from off-stage.*

Too wordy and kind of fatuous.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sound of X, upset, running down a staircase

Comment: Unless the playwright is trying to enthrall the director with the cleverness of the wording, it seems to me that the most direct and specific (without being over-specific) notation should be used.  And likely it is worthwhile to adopt a single style and stick with it (eg, "off-stage" before or after the direction -- pick one and stay with it).  And, of course, stay reasonably close to "industry standards".

Comment: @PeterShor: Let's up the ante. Someone's playing Chopin's polonaise in a nearby house. How would you put that in the blocking?

Comment: @HotLicks: My sentiments exactly. As for the industry standards, they don't exist. Most producers will insist, with vim and vigor, that they do. But they don't, not really. I'm all for Shakespearean brevity when it comes to blocking (hence the title of this question), but sadly, that's not enough today. Actors, and oftentimes directors themselves, just "don't get it." Things need to be explained.

Comment: Is this an American thing, to call stage directions "blocking"? I am very familiar with blocking meaning the director's activity of determining the positions and movements of the actors on stage; but even in the (comparatively rare) case where the script specifies all of these, I've never heard the specification in the script referred to as the blocking.

Comment: @Colin Fine: No, it's theatre slang. I know it sounds stupid. But what do actors know from "stage directions"? Stage directions include directions for the director, stage manager, and who knows who all else. Actors can't be bothered with all that. They have enough trouble dealing with what they know as the blocking. "I'm standing here and I have no lines. What do I do?" "You should be listening to the others and smiling sarcastically." "Says who? Ain't nothing like that in the blocking!"

Comment: Whatever you call it (I too understand it to be "stage directions", with "blocking" being the management of actors' movements on stage), in fact it is **technical writing**, and is no different, fundamentally, from writing the instructions to use a toaster.  This includes considering the likely education and experience of the reader and taking that into account when deciding on the level of detail and the complexity of the language used.

Comment: @HotLicks: - Yes; and yes; but you'll recall a character in Adams who read the instructions on a packet of q-tips and concluded that the world had gone insane. There's gotta be a golden ratio somewhere, some kind of (expletive) middle ground: say too little and they'll screw it up; put in three extra words, and they'll ignore it altogether.

Comment: That's where you show your skill as a writer.  (And the actors (and director) always screw up the play -- it's never the playwright's fault.)

Comment: @HotLicks: Ah, but whom do you show it TO, then? Shakespeare wasn't into writing much in the way of stage directions; and Shaw wrote entire novellas in italics - to what end? (Neither approach meets today's "standards," by the way, because WE know better than Shakespeare, and are certainly more professional than, what's his name again, Shaw?) The other day I spent an agonizing two and a half hours watching a BBC production of the play that made Shaw famous: "The Devil's Disciple." It's an eternal mystery to me how one can pick up a good play, get pretty good actors to perform it, and turn ...

Comment: ... the whole thing into a boring mess of miscues, botched jokes, and amateurish acting. Worse than a high school production, I swear.

Comment: I have seen some very excellent high school productions.

Comment: I have seen some pretty amazing professional productions. Exceptions don't change the rule.

Comment: @Ricky: it may be slang in your theatre: it's not in mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A woman hurrying down a set of stairs doesn't make a "patter". She makes a "clatter". (Unless she's wearing sneakers. But if she were we wouldn't be hearing the offstage noise!)

- Off-stage: the clatter of high-heeled shoes, quickly descending stairs.

Comment: And male/female?  Combat boots or high heels?

Comment: Point taken. Emending my answer.

Comment: Nah, Shakespeare is the master of this. You just need a chorus, who intervenes with commentary: "But hark, the clatter of high-heeled shoes, quickly descending the stairs."